# How i can configure dockerized WildFly with HornetQ?

Tags: jakarta-ee, docker, netty, wildfly, hornetq

I need access to HornetQ integrated to WildFly in my project. WildFly server should be started up as docker container.

I am sure linking between containers is good way, but I should provide part of my API to external clients for access to JMS and EJB.

All required ports, 8080, 4747 and etc. exposed from docker container and linked to public host machine.
JMS connection failed because client can't establish connection to wrong hostname, it's internal hostname of container.

Netty used as transport for JMS in HornetQ. Part of this configuration provided below.

It seems like netty provides containers hostname on protocol initialization! I should not bind netty to external interface.

What is right way for netty configuration in this way?

```xml
            <connectors>
                <netty-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                <netty-connector name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                </netty-connector>
                <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
            </connectors>
            <acceptors>
                <netty-acceptor name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                <netty-acceptor name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                    <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                </netty-acceptor>
            </acceptors>
```

Comment: Wildfly introduced a protocol upgrade capability so that you only need a single port.  Why do you need netty transport?

Comment: i should try it, tnx for idea. anyway, as i understand when jms used, that should have ability for disconnection policy and etc. my problem related to connection hornetq, which is "background" of wildfly and that use netty for communicftion.